# Telegram bot + группа, как исправить команды бота?

Tags: php, telegram

Настроил бота, все круто-замечательно, ток одного не пойму!
В приватной беседе, у бота команды / имеют вид - `/command`
Добавляю бота в группу и к ссылкам добавляется имя бота. Команды получают вид - `/command@name_bot`

И меня даже не вид больше смущает, а то, что при таком обращении он меня игнорирует, зато отвечает если убрать имя и вернуть первичный вариант. И все это работает и в привате и в группе

Как исправить, чтобы при добавлении в группу не происходило изменение ссылок?

Comment: Никак не убрать. Добавьте обработку просто.

Comment: т.е. в самой команде добавить вариант вызова с @name_bot, вы об этом?

Comment: Да, то есть 2 варианта команд